# Container Build Agents fail saying 'missing dll' TFS 2018 windows

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, docker

I just set up a few containerized agents and I'm running into build issues with few regression tests which work fine on regular build agents.

Was wondering if anyone had issues with containerized build agents?

**Error Log:**

> Add-Type : (0) : Unable to find messages file 'cscui.dll' (1) : namespace VstsTaskSdk.FS At C:\tfsagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\LongPathFunctions.ps1:212 char:1 + Add-Type -Debug:$false -TypeDefinition @' + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

#

> Unable to find type [VstsTaskSdk.TerminationException]. Exit code 1
>   returned from process: file name
>   'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe', arguments
>   '-NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
>   -Command ". ([scriptblock]::Create('if (!$PSHOME) { $null = Get-Item -LiteralPath ''variable:PSHOME'' } else { Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME,
>   ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1''))
>   ; Import-Module -Name ([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSHOME,
>   ''Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1''))
>   }')) 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose $_.Exception.Message
>   -Verbose } ; Import-Module -Name 'C:\tfsagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1'
>   -ArgumentList @{ NonInteractive = $true } -ErrorAction Stop ; $VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; $DebugPreference =
>   'SilentlyContinue' ; Invoke-VstsTaskScript -ScriptBlock
>   ([scriptblock]::Create('.
>   ''C:\tfsagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\VSBuild.ps1'''))"'.

Comment: looks like the module `'C:\tfsagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1` does not declare the `[VstsTaskSdk.TerminationException]`

Comment: The dotnet framework 4.7.1 image which I used to set the build tools as suggested my Microsoft seems to have some issue.
Pulled down the latest framework image 4.7.2 and I don't see this issue anymore! Thanks!